# Open a Table and Use the query designer for SQL 2008

Tags: sql-server

In SQL Server 2005 and managing my Crystal Reporting I used to open a table (small one) and then paste in the Crystal query. Using the Query designer I would add-remove tables and fields etc using all 4 of the Query Designer windows.

I understand that Open table has been replaced and I would be ok with that as I replace the SQL, but it does not bring up the query designer windows that give relationships or the field matrix

Answer (score 1):

The "Open table" item on the context menu has been replaced by "Edit Top 200 Rows"

After clicking the "Edit Top 200 Rows" menu, you will still have access to all of the query designer windows through the query designer menu and toolbar.

Comment: be sure to do EDIT top 200 rows and not SELECT top 200 rows. SELECT does not show the tools.